# what is sahifa?

Tags: prophets

**as far as** I Heard or Know that , allah revealed sahifa  to nabi  and Kitab (Quran,Injil,etc) revealed to rasul ...

1. Is it true ?
2. what is  sahifa ?

***Looking clarification...***

Comment: Please share the source of your knowledge because this is new to me! And the main difference between Nabi and Rasul is not the revelation, but their duty: The Rasul is a messenger he must spread the message, the Nabi must not. Therfore how Allah revealed to each is rather irrelevant however I doubt that Allah revealed something written because both Sahifa and Kitab are written texts and even the qur'an was revealed or transmitted orally ever since. The fact that we have a Moshaf is strictly speaking a bid'ah -linguistic perspective- and regarded by some scholars as benefit for the ummah.

Comment: @Sassir I agree with you.. it's a bid'ah.. actually I am looking for clarification ... I have no source...

Answer (score 1):

- Sahifa ( صحیفہ ) is the singular of Suhuf (صحف) that is used in Quran.
- It literally means pages/newspaper but in terminology of Quran, it’s also used for divine books/ scriptures.
- Divine books were revealed to many Messengers. Four of these are mentioned by name in Quran; Tawrat, Zaboor, Injeel and Quran.
- All the rest are mentioned with a general name; suhuf.
- The exact number of Suhuf (صحف)  is unknown
- This word is also used for Quran in the following verse;

> A Messenger from Allah, reciting purified scriptures [Surah Al-Bayyina Verse 2](https://qurano.com/en/98-al-bayyina/verse-2/)
> **[more..](https://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=SHf)**

Second Portion

**Torah which was revealed to Prophet Moses**

also in Quran

> Or has he not been informed of what was in the scriptures of Moses
> [Surah An-Najm Verse 36](https://qurano.com/en/53-an-najm/verse-36/)

Above this verse used plural `Suhuf (صحف)` form of Sahifa `( صحیفہ )`..

`allah revealed sahifa to nabi and Kitab (Quran,Injil,etc) revealed to rasul ...` It's not true...

Answer (score 0):

"Sahifa" means something that is expanded for writing. The sum of it is "Sahif" and "Sahif". And it means the tablets in which the divine knowledge and the rules and verses that were revealed to the prophets are written. The material of this sheet has been different according to different times. In some times it was made of wood, sometimes it was tanned leather, and sometimes it was made of paper. [1] in other words; The divine scriptures are the same books that were revealed to the prophets and in some verses they are referred to as tablets. [2]

For example, the tablets that were revealed to Moses refer to the Torah, which the Holy Qur'an has interpreted as tablets in several places. [3] This is why the Qur'an is also referred to as "Mus'haf".
[1]. Mustafavi, Hassan, Research in the words of the Holy Quran, vol. 6, p. 197, Tehran, Ministry of Culture and Islamic Guidance, first edition, 1989.
[2]. Bahrani, Sayyid Hashim ibn Sulayman, Al-Burhan Fi Tafsir Al-Quran, vol. 5, p. 638, Qom, Besat Institute, first edition, 1995.
[3]. Tabatabai, Mohammad Hussein, Al-Mizan Fi Tafsir Al-Quran, vol. 20, p. 273, Qom, Islamic Publications Office, fifth edition, 1417 AH.